# How do I query the value of a server option in Sybase?

Tags: t-sql, sybase

For example, if I wanted to know the current value of the `quoted_identifier` server option, is there a query that can give me this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the session-level options are available to you as a varbinary via the @@options variable. Some guidance on the interpretation of the bitmask is given by

http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/41423;pt=42621

and

http://www.isug.com/Sybase_FAQ/ASE/code/sp_helpoptions.sql

For the session options which are not documented (such as quoted_identifier), you may have to resort to experimentation. I ran the following on an Solaris x86 Sybase 15 instance and saw a change in the 'third bit from the right' (counting from zero)

It is an interesting question and one that had not occured to me in my seven or so years of Sybase admin.

pjjH

```
262:1> set quoted_identifier off
262:2> go
263:1> select @@options
263:2> go

 --------------------------
 80210000800f0144030010

(1 row affected)
264:1> set quoted_identifier on
264:2> go
265:1> select @@options
265:2> go

 --------------------------
 80210001800f0144030018

(1 row affected)


select @@options as options into #foo
```

Answer (score 1):

sp_dboption can give you a list of settable options or actually set the option:-

List Settable Options

```
exec sp_dboption
```

set an option

```
sp_dboption pubs2, "unique auto_identity index", true
```

If you just want to list the options set on a db, you can use sp_helpdb

```
sp_helpdb pubs2
```

This Yields a multi-page resultset but the first set has a column called 'status' which shows all the 'true' options in the nominated database.

Comment: whilst useful, sp_dboption doesn't provide the current value of the quoted_identifier option

Comment: Agreed, thats why I suggested you may be able to use sp_helpdb to get this information.

Comment: I think this is because quoted_identifier is a session option, and not a server or database setting. There doesn't seem to be a way of querying the current value.
I think you'll need to explicitly set it to whatever setting you require.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to query the current value set on selected option.

It is in code of `sp_helpdb` procedure.

You can check `sp_helptext` `sp_helpdb` on sybsystemprocs database but it is very complicated.